# ffmpeg error: AttributeError: 'FilterableStream' object has no attribute 'global_args'

Tags: python-3.x, ffmpeg, ffmpeg-python

I got the error while using ffmpeg.

```
Error:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "D:\\1. OTH\\NOWWW\\DDDD\\main.py", line 593, in confirmExecute
            self.execute()
        File "D:\\1. OTH\\NOWWW\\DDDD\\main.py", line 652, in execute
            .global_args('-progress', 'unix://{}'.format(self.filename))
        AttributeError: 'FilterableStream' object has no attribute 'global_args'
```

This what I tried:

```
        (ffmpeg
            .input(self.txtSourcePath.toPlainText())
            .global_args('-progress', 'unix://{}'.format(self.filename))
            .overwrite_output()
            .output(
            self.txtDestinationPath.toPlainText() + "/" + self.filename + "\_%02d." + self.fileExtension,
            map=0, f='segment', segment_time='100', c='copy')
            .run()
        )
```

If anyone know this, please help me!
Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

`output()` has to come before `global_args()` etc.